# Pytest unable to find file that is found by python

Tags: python, module, path, pytest

I have found many similar problems listed, but none of the existing threads discusses this exact scenario.

I have a simple python module and pytest:

```
project
    \mymod
        __init__.py
        const.py
        mymodclass.py
    \tests
        test_mymodclass.py
    conftest.py
```

My module implementation class includes the const.py file in order to use a CONSTANT:

```
from const import CONSTANT

class MyModClass:
    def initialize(self):
        return CONSTANT

def main():
    test_mod = MyModClass()
    test_mod.initialize()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running `mymodclass.py` works just fine.
Running `python mymodclass.py` works just fine.

Now I want to run some pytest unit tests. Those are found in `test_mymodclass.py`:

```
from mymod.mymodclass import MyModClass

test_mod = MyModClass()
assert( test_mod.initialize() == CONSTANT )
```

However, running `pytest` from the `project` folder causes an error:

```
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'const'
```

It appears that pytest cannot find `const.py` that is found by `mymodclass.py` in the local folder.

I can change `mymodclass.py` to import `from mymod.const import *` and pytest will work!
Unfortunately, now python cannot execute `mymodclass.py` directly from the `mymod` folder:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymod'
```

It appears that I can either make python happy or pytest happy, but not both.

Comment: `from mymod.mymod-class import MyModClass` is not a valid Python syntax

Comment: Could you specify why not?  I am currently using that syntax and it works just fine.

I can use
`from mymod.mymod-class import MyModClass`
or
`from mymod.mymod-class import *`

Comment: See [the grammar of a module name](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-module). A "-" shall not be part of a module name. Even if that works in some cases, it will break in other cases (as you have noticed).

Comment: Fair enough. I should have copy-pasted my code. I retyped some of it to make the names generic. My code does not actually use a `-` symbol. I will edit my original post to remove the `-` symbol.

Comment: While I wish this was the simple solution, this does not appear to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `import const` works when running `python mymodclass.py` from inside the `project/mymod` directory is because Python adds the current working directory to `sys.path`. This allows `const` to be resolved to `./const.py`.

However, when running the tests, the current working directory is likely `project/`, so attempting to import `const` will try to resolve `project/const.py`, which does not exist. Changing it to `mymod.const` will resolve the module to `project/mymod/const.py`, which works.

If you want to run `mymodclass.py` directly, while still using `import mymod.const`, ensure the working directory is `project/`, and invoke the script as `python mymod/mymodclass.py`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that trying to run both the tests and the class will not work with the same code IF trying to run from their respective folder.

In the end, I need to execute from the project folder. Then I can run
```pytest``` or
```python mymod/mymodclass.py```

Comment: Clarification: in order to run MyModClass code, it is necessary to run `python -m mymod.mymodclass`